# How to filter relevant objects with Neo4j OGM typed query?

Tags: neo4j, mapping, cypher, neo4j-ogm

Let's say my graph model contains nodes of type A that have parent/child relations with other nodes of the same type.

```
@NodeEntity(label = "A")
class A {
    @Relationship(type = "PARENT")
    private A parent;

    // other relations to different types
    ...

}
```

I'm using following session method to execute complex queries (for paging, filtering, optional matches etc)

```
session.query(A.class, cypher, parameters)
```

where the cypher statement is something like

```
MATCH (node:A) WHERE ... OPTIONAL MATCH ... RETURN node, ... ORDER BY node.id ASC LIMIT 100
```

Now, I also want to fetch the parent node(s) for each result (which are also of type A). For this, I extended my query with

```
MATCH (node:A) WHERE ... OPTIONAL MATCH parentRels=(node)-[parentRel:PARENT*1..]->(:A) RETURN node, collect(parentRel) ORDER BY node.id ASC LIMIT 100
```

What I naively expected to see is my same list of objects A, where each parent field is nicely filled, up to the root.
The result returned by Neo4j is correct, but the mapped result returned by the OGM is useless because now it doesn't just contain my nodes of interest (with the parent fields correctly filled, yes), but all the parent nodes also end up in the result list!

So I started looking for a hidden OGM feature where I could specify the result column ('node' in the example above) with nodes of interest but this doesn't seem to be possible.

The only solutions I see are:

- fetch parent nodes in separate queries :(
- do the mapping myself :( :(
- fetch the relevant ids in a separate query and filter based on that.

Maybe someone sees a better solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this is that your parents also match the type you pass in the `query` method - the `A.class`.

OGM has no way to know what your actual wanted result is and hence maps all matching nodes to the result - one row may result in 2 or even more items in the result list. (Note that some people have the opposite use case and actually want that to happen).

You can also collect results from a result column manually, provided you return all relationships and related nodes it will be mapped correctly:

```
Result result = session.query(cypher, parameters)
for(Map<String, Object> map : result.queryResults()) {
    (A) map.get("node"); // collect result manually to some collection
}
```

Apart from what you listed you also can

- Provide different type/label for the parent
- Have the parents loaded in your session and return only node and relationship, not whole path - something like `RETURN node,parentRel` instead

You might want to fill in an issue here https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-ogm/issues for a better way to solve this.

Comment: Thx for your response. Using different labels is no option as we're really talking about the same node type. About your second option, if I only return the relationships, then I won't be able to navigate through my nodes afaik. I'll fill an issue as this doesn't seem such an isolated use case...

Comment: @Christian Just remembered there is another way.. see edited answer

Comment: I thought that would give me raw data (not mapped objects), but I'll certainly look into it!

Comment: After some testing this looks promising, but for some reason the returned nodes don't contain all data from the optional matches, whereas they do using query(A.class, cypher, parameters)... weird.

Comment: @Christian Note that you need to return both relationship and node from the optimal match(es) plus all the base node and other things..

Comment: Yes that's the case, I'll need to look into it further. In the meantime I'll accept your answer because that's how it's supposed to work ;)